# How do I reference the output of a project in a different solution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In my current project, in Solution X, how do I reference the output of a class library project in a different solution, Solution Y? If I can't reference (I haven't found a way) the output, what is the best way to get the same outcome?

Update - these are c# projects, .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

In the project in solution X right click on `References` and select `Add reference`. This opens the **Add reference** dialogue. In this dialogue click on `Browse` and navigate to the output directory of solution Y. Select the desired assembly. After completion be sure to set the reference's property: `Copy local = true`.